# Angular UI route parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, angular-routing, angular-ui-router-extras

I have this pattern in my route.js

```
.state('organizations', {
        url: '/companies/:options?/:keyvalue',
        templateUrl: '../app/components/organizations/organization.html',
        controller: 'OrganizationController',
        controllerAs: 'organizationsCtrl'
      })
```

And when I try access the URLs

```
/companies/
/companies/users
```

It works ok, but when I try

```
/companies/users/1
```

It redirects to the default view

```
// For any unmatched url, redirect to /dashboard
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');
```

Anyone can help me to see what I am doing wrong? 
thanks!

Comment: why the `?` in the url ?

Comment: I use it to set that is an optional parameter, as I read on another post

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you wanted to make the `options` parameters optional.

Route parameters in UI Router are optional by default.

The `?` suffix on route parameters simply tells UI Router where the query portion of the URL template should start

Your url should then looks like this `url: '/companies/:options/:keyvalue'`

This will match

```
/companies/
/companies/users/
/companies/users/1
```

Comment: Without the ? , I can not access even to /companies/ that's why I add it

Comment: If you go to `/companies/users/1` that go to the otherwise state ?

Comment: exactly, but, if I put the ? on url: '/companies/:options?/:keyvalue' , at least goes to /companies/ /companies/users/

Comment: Remove the `?`. It does **not** say that the parameter is optionnal.

Comment: I did it, but now I can not access to /companies even, really weird